# Milliseconds to readable format?

Tags: c++

I want to convert milliseconds to a human readable string.

So it looks something like 1:59:23 (1 hour, 59 minutes, 23 seconds).

I've tried this:

```
    int hours = (metaData["duration"].toInt()/(1000 * 60 * 60));
    int mins = (metaData["duration"].toInt()/(1000 * 60));
    int seconds = (metaData["duration"].toInt()/1000);
```

But this just gives out the total, ie, it will say the total amount of mins and total amount of seconds, it does not take in to account that 60 seconds becomes a minute, so do not include it in the seconds count.

Does anyone have a way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: Is this managed C++? What is `metaData`?

Comment: Aside from the sophisticated answers, why don't you just subtract the minutes times 60 from the seconds and the hours times 60 from the minutes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the modulus function to extract how many minutes and seconds there are.

```
int hours = (metaData["duration"].toInt()/(1000 * 60 * 60));
int mins = (metaData["duration"].toInt()/(1000 * 60)) % 60;
int seconds = (metaData["duration"].toInt()/1000) % 60;
```

The modulus function returns the remainder when divided by something. So, using `% 60` you end up with the number of seconds there are, ignoring full minutes, and likewise for minutes.

Answer (score 1):

Just slightly modify your code.

```
int hours = (metaData["duration"].toInt()/(1000 * 60 * 60));
// 60 mins = 1 hour
int mins = (metaData["duration"].toInt()/(1000 * 60)) % 60;
// 60 secs = 1 min
int seconds = (metaData["duration"].toInt()/1000) % 60;
```

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code where **totalf** holds the millisecond value and output is of type:

Days.Hours:Minutes:Seconds.Millisecods e.g. 12.23:59:59.123

```
unsigned int r,d,h,m,s,f;
r = abs(totalf);
d = r / 86400000;
r = r % 86400000;
h = r / 3600000;
r = r % 3600000;
m = r / 60000;
r = r % 60000;
s = r / 1000;
f = r % 1000;

char str[128];

if (totalf<0)
    sprintf(str, "-%d.%02d:%02d:%02d.%03d", d, h, m, s, f);
else
    sprintf(str, "%d.%02d:%02d:%02d.%03d", d, h, m, s, f);
```